# Resources for learning about theta functions

Tags: online-resources, theta-functions

I would like to learn about the Jacobi theta functions,however, I'm struggling to find a free ebook /website that would introduce the functions in a detailed comprehensible manner for beginners. So is there any source that can help me learn about the theta functions?

Comment: 18 bucks for ebook on specialized topic is pretty much free https://www.amazon.com.au/Brief-Introduction-Functions-RICHARD-BELLMAN/dp/0486492958

Comment: See [Tkachev, Elliptic functions:
Introduction course](https://users.mai.liu.se/vlatk48/teaching/lect2-agm.pdf), and [Franz, Theta functions](http://banach.ucd.ie/bull60/R6004.pdf).

Comment: The theory of theta functions and related topics is very interesting (almost seductive). I have to tried to present this in a coherent way using mostly real analysis tools and covered both the approaches of Jacobi and Ramanujan. Most of Ramanujan's mysterious formulas are proved in systematic fashion. See [archives page](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/p/archives.html?m=0).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I checked out your archeive pages and they helped me alot,really liked how yyou represented the methods in a clear manner that is clear to understand, keep up the great work!

Comment: @mathlover123: btw this topic requires a bit of patience to digest. So take your time. And do ask your doubts on math se